# In R, is there are way to edit/change one script's code from another script?

Tags: r

Let's say I use script1.R to source script2.R as follows:

```
source("./script2.R")
```

In script2.R, I have the following code on line 1:

```
[1] some_number <- 1
```

But before sourcing the script2.R file, I want to first edit the script2.R code from script1.R. Is there any way for me to edit the code in script2.R directly from script1.R such that, for instance, `some_number <- 1` changes to `some_number <- 2`?

Moreover, is there a way to *save* script2.R externally from script1.R after making those changes? Or do I have to manually open script2.R to save it?

Comment: .R programs are text files so you can use typical regex commands to make the changes. I would recommend using the file.copy/file.rename functions to copy the file first, rename it and then make the changes.

Comment: Although I don't see your real intention, I would advise against that kind of organization. It can become messy very quickly so that you don't know where are your variables. You can build a function that does this job in script2.R. `myfun <- function(x) some_number <<- x`. Then in script1.R `myfun(3)`,  would assign 3 to some_number in the global environment. Again this organization can be dangerous,